# Show that if $N = p^c$ for some prime $p$ and $a = p^c + 1 − p^{c−1}$, then $a^{N−1} \not≡ 1 \bmod N$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Show that if $N = p^c$ for some prime $p$, then taking $a = p^c + 1 − p^{c−1}$, then $a^{N−1} \not≡ 1 \bmod N$ because $a^{N−1} ≡ p^{c−1} + 1 \bmod N$ and $p^{c−1} + 1 \not≡ 1\bmod N$

I am reading these notes on quantum computation and came across this exercise, but I'm unsure how to go about proving it.
Any help is greatly appreciated as I have been fumbling around with some algebra to no avail for quite some time.

Comment: When you write $!\equiv $ do you mean $\not \equiv$?  It looks like you mean factorial.

Comment: Yes I mean  ≢ ! I didn't know how to write it. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem.  The syntax is "\not \equiv ".

Comment: I would suggest familiarizing yourself with the basics of modular arithmetic if you aren't already. For starters, note that the $p^c$ term in the definition of $a$ is just taken to get a 'positive' $a$, but for your math you might as well just say $a\equiv1-p^{c-1}$. Next, take this expression for $a$ — we can define $b=-p^{c-1}$, so $a=1+b$ to make it a bit easier — and just use the binomial theorem to raise it to the $(N-1)$st power. You should find that $a^{N-1}=1+(N-1)b+Cb^2+Db^3+\ldots$, for some values $C, D$, etc.

Comment: Then note that any power of $b$ greater than the first is $\equiv 0\bmod N$ (can you see why that would be?), so $a^{N-1}\equiv 1+(N-1)b \equiv 1-b\bmod N$.

Comment: Thank You! But, how could every power of b greater than the first be $\equiv 0 mod N$ ? For example, $b^2$ is $p^{2c-2}$ and when you divide that by $N$ you get $p^{c-2}$, but if $c = 1$ then you could get $p^{-1}$ which would not be an integer. @StevenStadnicki

Comment: @imconfused if $c=1$ then the theorem is trivially true; then $N=p^1=p$ and $a=p^1+1-p^0$ $=p+1-1$ $=p=N$, so $a^i\equiv 0\bmod N$ for all nonzero $i$. (And this is the only case in which the above breaks down; otherwise, $k\cdot(c-1) \gt c$ for all $k\gt 1$, so divisibility works. You should try and prove this, though!)